# Firebase firestore query doesn't seem to work with React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, axios

I have spend 6 hours on this problem and still can't wrap my head around it. I'm trying to query orders by order status with firestore. But for some reason the function doesn't work when I add .where in it. I have tried querying with other fields and it doesn't work either.

```
exports.getOrderHistory = (req, res) => {
  return db
     .collection('orders')
     .where('orderStatus', '==', "Active")  //this line doesnt work 
     .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
     .get()
     .then((data) =>{
         let orders =[];
         data.forEach((doc)=>{
          orders.push(doc.data()

             );
         })
         return res.json(orders)
     })
     .catch((err) =>{
        console.error(err)
        res.status(500).json({error:err.code})
    })
}
```

However, I have used it to get an authentication token from "user" collection and it works perfectly fine.

```
  let idToken;
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ")
  ) {
    idToken = req.headers.authorization.split("Bearer ")[1];
  } else {
    console.error("No token found");
    return res.status(403).json({ error: "Unauthorised" });
  }

  admin
    .auth()
    .verifyIdToken(idToken)
    .then(decodedToken => {
      req.user = decodedToken;
      return db
        .collection("users")
        .where("userId", "==", req.user.uid) // it works fine here
        .limit(1)
        .get();
    })
    .then(data => {
      req.user.handle = data.docs[0].data().handle;
      return next();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.err("Error while verifying token", err);
      return res.status(403).json(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: " the function doesn't work when I add `.where` in it" What doesn't work about it?

Comment: I guess I would be doing little things to try to debug. Not mixing single and double quotes in "where", checking case sensitivity for "Active"

Comment: When you say not working are you getting errors? Or, just not the results you anticipate?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i cross posted my question on reddit. u/pagerussel found the culprit, which was orderBy(). "An orderBy() clause also filters for existence of the given field. The result set will not include documents that do not contain the given field." It seems that my orderby field was null. As for error, I didnt get any error in vscode it just simply didnt return my api call. I tried it with Postman and it returned error:9 (i think it has something to do with authorization, but im not sure)

Comment: Please provide a link to that question, so folks can read the answer there. Or post it as an answer here, but in that case please still link to the reddit post.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/e97yon/firestore_query_doesnt_work/fah4hsx?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

Answer (score 0):

> From the docs
>
> An orderBy() clause also filters for existence of the given field. The
>   result set will not include documents that do not contain the given
>   field.
>
> Is it possible your order by field is null?
>
> [/u/pagerussell](https://reddit.com/u/pagerussell)

The answer was cross posted on reddit and can be found here

https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/e97yon/firestore_query_doesnt_work/fah4hsx?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your rules match your query. In other words, if you are adding "where", you must mention it in the Rules as well. I know this is an old question but I am answering it just in case, it may help someone else.